# About the new 2SXC custom field GPS Picker

Tags: 2sxc

I used the new GPS Picker custom field in a test project to learn the product. I found a generic link that describes it here: https://2sxc.org/en/Docs/GPS-Picker but nowhere could I find how to access only the latitude or longitude separately using the @content data access in the view and I'm no able to go on.
Little help could help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPS field is a bit exotic - since it kind of delivers 2 values. We have a pending wish to implement more complex fields, but ATM the mechanism is as such, that the field is configured to put these two values in two number fields. These must be specified in the settings.

[image]

Comment: Very thanks, it is more simply it's much simpler than I thought.